# Using multiple checkboxes to generate results with ng-show

Tags: angularjs

I'm having an issue with a web form I'm putting together

The aim is for the user to check a series of check boxes and then be presented with a range of tip that relate to those check boxes

Here is a condensed version of what I have so far:

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {

    $scope.tips = [
    {   

        heading: "Handy Tip Number 1",
        body : "This is a great tip you're sure to love it",
        usp: false,
        cleargoal: true


    },
    {
            heading: "Handy Tip Number 2",
        body : "This is a great tip you're sure to love it",
        usp: true,
        cleargoal: true

    },
    {
        heading: "Handy Tip Number 3",
        body : "This is a great tip you're sure to love it",
        usp: true,
        cleargoal: false


    },
    {
        heading: "Handy Tip Number 4",
        body : "This is a great tip you're sure to love it",
        usp: false,
        cleargoal: false

    },
    {
        heading: "Handy Tip Number 5",
        body : "This is a great tip you're sure to love it",
        usp: false,
        cleargoal: true,


    }
]});
```

and

```
    <form >
        <input ng-model="easyTips" type="radio" value="usp" name="usp">

</form>

<form >
        <input ng-model="hardTips" value="cleargoal" type="radio" name="clear goal" >


</form>



<div div ng-controller="MyController">
            <div ng-repeat="items in tips">
                    <div ng-show="items[easyTips] || items[hardTips]">
                            <h2>{{items.heading}}</h2>
                            <p>{{items.body}}</p>
                    </div>  

            </div>
    </div>
```

That is working, however instead of radio buttons, I want the inputs to be check boxes so the user can select and deselect multiple options and I can't find anything on how to make that change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use `ng-true-value` with `type="checkbox"` and set it to `'usp'` or `'cleargoal'` so that whenever the user checks the `checkbox` the `easyTips` and `hardTips` `ng-model` shall have those values respectively.

```
<form >
        <input ng-model="easyTips" type="checkbox" ng-true-value="'usp'" />
{{easyTips}}
</form>

<form >
        <input ng-model="hardTips" ng-true-value="'cleargoal'"  type="checkbox" name="clear goal">
        {{hardTips}}


</form>
```

**[FULL EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/5cjpybvw/7/)**

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Use type="checkbox" instead of type="radio" on particular input boxes.